# How to get GIF transparency color for saving with GD?

Tags: php, image, gd, gif

My GD wrapper works like charm with JPEG and PNG images, however when using GIF image the resulting image loses transparency.

Further search suggests i have to use `imagecolortransparent` (sets the transparent color) after getting color identifier with:

`imagecolorallocate (resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue)`.

So **question** is: how can i get original transparecy color (RGB)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the GIF image is loaded into resource $image... try the following

```
$index_of_transparent_colour = imagecolortransparent($image);
if($index_of_transparent_colour != -1) {
    $actual_transparent_colour = imagecolorsforindex($image,$index_of_transparent_colour);
}
```

Should be able to access the actual RGB values from

```
$actual_transparent_colour['red']
$actual_transparent_colour['green'] 
$actual_transparent_colour['blue']
```

Hope this helps :)

Love to all :)