# How to get pixel color information from gd string ? gd imagecreatefromstring() does not reproduce the same image if i add alpha

Tags: php, gd, gif

I have gif image with transparency, which i would like to convert to string, to save to database, and later retrieve from database and read pixel colors and transparencies. But after i convert image to string, i am not able to get the original image back. Base64 decoded and original strings looks the same. 
But i am not able to recreate the image colors and transparencies from the decoded string?? 
I have tried `imagecreatefromstring()` , and tried to put the string to file and than use `imagecreatefromgif()`. Both these functions produce different pixel color then original was.

But how to create gd image from compressed string?
I need to get pixel colors. 
Thus i need gd object, in order to use gd functions.

In the beginning(step2) the first pixel was `20,20,20,20` (RGBA)

after(step7) conversion to string, encoding, decoding the first pixel is `20,22,20,0` (RGBA)

differs G color and transparency

If using other numbers, sometimes differs all four RGBA color parameters.
How to resolve and why it may happen?

```
<?php

$width = 300;
$height = 300;

//1) Create image 
$img = imageCreateTrueColor($width, $height); //ImageCreate (width, height)
imagealphablending($img, false); //wihtout these two does not work
imagesavealpha($img, true); //without these two does not work 

//2)Put a pixel on the image
$c1 = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($img, 20, 20, 20, 20);
imagesetpixel ( $img , 0 , 0 , $c1);

//check pixel data
$cat = imagecolorat( $img, 0 ,0 );
$cfi = imagecolorsforindex($img, $cat); 
echo '<br><br> 17 before decoding cat='.$cat.',   cfi = '; print_r($cfi); 
// 17 before decoding cat=336860180, cfi = Array ( [red] => 20 [green] => 20 [blue] => 20 [alpha] => 20 ) 

//3) convert image to string
ob_start(); 
    imagegif( $img );//imagegif — Output image to browser or file
    $image_data = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
echo '<br><br> ***********************************<br> image_data='. $image_data; 
//GIF87a,,�,,,��������ڋ�޼���H�扦�ʶ���L�������� �Ģ�L*�̦�  �J�Ԫ���j�ܮ������N���� �������������(8HXhx��������)9IYiy�������� *:JZjz�������� +;K[k{��������,N^n~��������/?O_o��������0���<�0�:|1�ĉ+Z��1�Ƨ�;z�2�ȑ$K�<�2�ʕ,[�|  3�̙4kڼ�3�Ν<{��  4�СD�=�4�ҥL�:} 5�ԩT�Z��5�֭\�z� 6�رd˚=�6�ڵlۺ}7�ܹt�ڽ�7�޽|���8����>�8��Ō;~9��ɔ+[��9��͜;{�:��ѤK�>�:��լ�;

//4) encode the string, in order to save to datbase, etc... 
$img64str = base64_encode($image_data); 
echo '<br><br> ***********************************<br> img64='. $img64str; 
//img64=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

//5) decode the string retrieved from database, file, etc.... 
$imgdec = base64_decode($img64str); // =$image_data
echo '<br><br> ***********************************<br> imgdec='. $imgdec; 
//GIF87a,,�,,,��������ڋ�޼���H�扦�ʶ���L�������� �Ģ�L*�̦�  �J�Ԫ���j�ܮ������N���� �������������(8HXhx��������)9IYiy�������� *:JZjz�������� +;K[k{��������,N^n~��������/?O_o��������0���<�0�:|1�ĉ+Z��1�Ƨ�;z�2�ȑ$K�<�2�ʕ,[�|  3�̙4kڼ�3�Ν<{��  4�СD�=�4�ҥL�:} 5�ԩT�Z��5�֭\�z� 6�رd˚=�6�ڵlۺ}7�ܹt�ڽ�7�޽|���8����>�8��Ō;~9��ɔ+[��9��͜;{�:��ѤK�>�:��լ�;

//6a) create a new image from the string (try or 6a or 6b - produce the same, G color is 22 instead of 20, transparency is 0 instead of 20)
$imgD = imagecreatefromstring( $imgdec ); 

//6b)
file_put_contents( __DIR__ . 'px1.gif', $imgdec );
$imgD = imagecreatefromgif( __DIR__ . 'px1.gif' );


//END 7) you see that the first pixel data differs
$cat = imagecolorat( $imgD, 0 ,0 );
$cfi = imagecolorsforindex( $imgD, $cat ); 
echo '<br><br> 112 cat='.$cat.',   cfi = '; print_r( $cfi ); 
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $fname );
echo ' width='.$width.', $height'.$height.', $type'.$type.', $attr'.$attr;
//112 cat=1, cfi = Array ( [red] => 20 [green] => 22 [blue] => 20 [alpha] => 0 ) width=, $height, $type, $attr
```

If i in step6 use function `$imgD = imagecreatefromgif( $imgdec );`
then i am not getting pixel data at all :
`112 cat=, cfi = width=, $height, $type, $attr`

Comment: seems this could be a solution, but implementation is kind of work : http://www.codediesel.com/php/unpacking-binary-data/,    http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/index.html

Comment: It works with `ImageColorAllocate()`, if there is not transparency - it is possibel to create from the string

Comment: seems this is alse a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528903/how-to-get-gif-transparency-color-for-saving-with-gd?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

With this it is possible to recover pixel color, though not transparency :

```
// 1-2) Create image with single pixel : 
$img = imageCreateTrueColor($width, $height); 
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$c1 = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($img, 20, 20, 20, 20);
imagecolortransparent($img, $c1);
imagesetpixel ( $img , 0 , 0 , $c1);
//3) convert image to string
ob_start(); 
    imagegif( $img );//imagegif — Output image to browser or file
    $image_data = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
//4) encode the string, in order to save to datbase, etc... 
$img64str = base64_encode($image_data); 

//5) decode the string retrieved from database, file, etc.... 
$imgdec = base64_decode($img64str); // =$image_data
```

Then to recover the pixel colors (but it does not find pixel transparency value) :

```
$imgD = imagecreatefromstring( $imgdec ); 
imagealphablending($imgD, false); //wihtout these two does not work
imagesavealpha($imgD, true); //without these two does not work 
$cat = imagecolorat( $imgD, 0 ,0 );
$cfi = imagecolorsforindex( $imgD, $cat ); 
//echoes cfi = Array ( [red] => 20 [green] => 20 [blue] => 20 [alpha] => 127 )
```

Additionally, saving `img` to file, i do not see the colors i set.
For example, if i set `$c1 = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($img, 179, 29, 20, 0);`, which is dark red, i can see in the image file (`imagegif( $img, $fname );`) that color is grey, in both cases, before and after encoding/decoding. 
Maybe i do not understaNd how transparency works? Maybe it is not for sepArate colors, but for the background only ?

Concluded, that if you need colors and transparencies, better use svg, for example : https://github.com/jasonlong/geo_pattern. Transparencies and colors are working. Additionally, base64 encoded strings are shorter. And this package has implementations in many languages, including `php` ( https://github.com/RedeyeGroup/geopattern-php ) and `javascript` ( https://github.com/btmills/geopattern ).

Comment: anyway, i found that base64 encoded svg strings are shorter and much better than gif images.